# SweetAlert on Status alert

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

I am using SweetAlert in Laravel 8.  When a user resets their password, it is redirecting them to the login page.  This works.  I want a sweetalert in the login page displaying password was changed.  Currently I have this:

```
@if(session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      {{ session('error') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

How can I change it to have the following instead of {{ session('error') }}

```
alert()->success('Password Updated','User Password Updated Successfully!!!');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used sweetalerts but i will guide you how to make your own alerts function.

Step 1:

Create a new folder in "resources/views/layouts/" and name it "includes".
In folder "includes" create a new file and name it "flash-messages.blade.php"
*you should now have "resources\views\layouts\includes\flash-messages.blade.php"*

Paste this code in "flash-messages.blade.php" and save the file.

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Success!</strong> {{ $message }}
</div>
@endif

@if ($message = Session::get('error'))
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Error!</strong> {{ $message }}
</div>
@endif

@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Error!</strong> Something whent wrong!
</div>
@endif


@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Step 2:
Include the file "flash-messages.blade.php" in your app.blade.php.
Open "app.blade.php" and paste this code right after `<main>` tag.

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            @include('layouts.includes.flash-messages')
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Your `<main>` tag in "app.blade.php" should looks like:

```
<main class="py-4">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            @include('layouts.includes.flash-messages')
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    @yield('content')
</main>
```

Step 3:
Include jquery and javascript for auto close the alert.
In "app.blade.php" just before `</body>` add those scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".alert").delay(4000).slideUp(500, function() {
    $(this).alert('close');
});
</script>
```

This script will close the alert after 4 seconds. you can adjust the time at this line `delay(4000)`

**Because you include the**

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

**in the "flash-messages.blade.php" make sure you remove it from any other blade files it might exist so you avoid the message to show twice**

Final step:
in your controllers you can call the alert with:

```
->with('success', 'Your Success message!');
```

or

```
->with('error', 'Your Error message!');
```

If you did everything right you can test it by forcing an error at the register page. Simply try create a user with wrong password and confirm password. this will trigger the alert.